# bash osx open file via variable or pipe

Tags: macos, bash

I would like to open a file using the osx open command, but all I have is a variable containing the filename (and path) instead of the filename itself.
I tried:

```
thisfile=./filename.extension
open $thisfile
```

and

```
thisfile=./filename.extension
printf $thisfile | open
```

and

```
printf ./filename.extension | open
```

but in all of these attempts I just get

```
Usage: open [-e] [-t] [-f] [-W] [-R] [-n] [-g] [-h] [-b <bundle identifier>] [-a <application>] [filenames] [--args arguments]
Help: Open opens files from a shell.
```

... (full text: http://pastie.org/10074666)

What am I doing wrong? How can I open the file through a pipe and with a variable?

---

EDIT/solution:

I did have spaces (and parentheses) which I escaped with `\` before storing in the variable. It turns out I should not have done that and I should have used `open "${thisfile}"` not `open $thisfile`

so for file

```
./foo - moo/zoo - boo (100)/poo (too).jpg
```

open with open via variable like this

```
thisfile='./foo - moo/zoo - boo (100)/poo (too).jpg'
open "${thisfile}"
```

Comment: is there a space in your file name? Are you getting `invalid option: xxx`?

Comment: Your first command works on OSX Yosemite. I don't think the other 2 will work because `open` doesn't read its `stdin`, rather it uses a parameter.

Comment: If your filename has spaces in it, use `thisfile="name with spaces"`, and `open "$thisfile"`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Since `open` doesn't read its `stdin` what would you do if you had an output of file names (space delimited) and wanted open to open them? My solution was to store the output string to a variable and use `open "${variable}"` like I edited above.

Comment: @MarkSetchell or instead of space delimited, newline delimited since filenames contain spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mark-setchell commented about it, open does not take anything on stdin. So let's understand what would be wrong with the first scenario.

when you try to open a file using the `open` command on OSX, I see three main scenarios:

① the file does not exist or has spaces:

```
 % open doesnotexists
The file /path/to/doesnotexists does not exist.
Usage: …
 % open has spaces
The files /path/to/has and /path/to/pyodsdiff/spaces do not exist.
Usage: …
```

② the file contains a dash:

```
 % open -notanoption
open: invalid option -- n
Usage: …
 % open --notanoption
open: invalid option `--notanoption'
Usage: …
```

③ the variable contains nothing:

```
 % open
 Usage: …
```

So, it looks like it's ③! i.e.: however you're declaring your variable, you're failing to do it.

To test how you're declaring your variable, just use `echo` instead of `open`:

```
% thisfile=README.md echo $thisfile

% thisfile=README.md
% echo $thisfile
README.md
% thisotherfile=README.md ; echo $thisotherfile
README.md
```

Comment: very helpful esp since I could not see a specific error being returned (just http://pastie.org/10074666). With my actual file that looked like `./foo - moo/zoo - boo (100)/poo (too).jpg` I had been trying to do `$ `thisfile='./foo\ -\ moo/zoo\ -\ boo\ \(100\)/poo\ \(too\).jpg'` then `$ open $thisfile` When I should have not bothered escaping spaces and (), and used `$ open "${thisfile}"` I'm not sure if it's the most elegant solution but it does work. If you know of a way to use **open** in a pipe, feel free to add, in the meantime i will try this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49019

Comment: you can use the output of a command to fill a variable: `MYVAR=$(find . -name 'README.md') ; open $(MYVAR)` which might open multiple files with paths that have _no spaces_, or using `MYVAR=$(find . -name 'README.md') ; open "$(MYVAR)"` if it has spaces. If you got multiple files and spaces into your files' paths, you might want to use the `-exec` option of find, or use `OLDIFS=$IFS;IFS=$'\n'; for f in $MYVAR; do open "$f"; done;IFS=$OLDIFS`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have newline delimited filenames in a variable called `filelist`, then I think you would need to do something like this:

```
echo -e $filelist | while IFS=$'\n' read f; do open "$f"; done
```

Comment: this did the trick with the advantage of opening each file individually, which matters when they are sent to Preview.app (though I realize I neither specified multiple files nor the need to open them individually or together in my original question). I'd like to add that I was able to open them together by making `filelist` a file and populating an array in bash4, one line per element, then doing `open "${array[@]}"` similar to: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174117